# Can you assign associative arrays to variables in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a few different associative arrays as variables:

```
declare -A FIRST=( [hello]=world [foo]=bar )
declare -A SECOND=( [bonjour]=monde [fu]=ba )
```

What I'd like to be able to do is take a third variable and assign it to one or the other, something like:

```
usethisarray=$FIRST
```

or maybe

```
declare -a usethisarray=$FIRST
```

But neither of those really work.  Can I get a level of indirection to point at the associative array I need?

Comment: Is that case sensitivity biting? `-a` vs `-A`?

Comment: Sorry, I typed it in here wrong.  I did use -A in the actual script, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note to readers: this answer is from 2013. You should now be using @ryenus's answer.

---

bash has [variable indirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) but it's kind of a pain to use:

```
$ declare -A FIRST=( [hello]=world [foo]=bar )
$ alias=FIRST
$ echo "${!alias[foo]}"

$ item=${alias}[foo]
$ echo ${!item}
bar
```

Comment: That's it, that's what I was looking for.  And you're right, it is kind of a pain to use.  Sigh...

Comment: This is not really the right answer, you need a **nameref**, see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70070402/537554/): https://stackoverflow.com/a/70070402/537554

Comment: In my defence, namerefs were a pretty new feature in 2013.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, and the reference variable needs to be a **nameref** for it to be used with arrays:

```sh
declare -A FIRST=( [hello]=world [foo]=bar )
declare -A SECOND=( [bonjour]=monde [fu]=ba )

#### ordinary variable assignment does NOT work
declare any_var=FIRST
echo -e '${any_var[@]}:' "${any_var[@]}"
echo -e '${!any_var[@]}:' "${!any_var[@]}"
echo -e '${#any_var[@]}:' "${#any_var[@]}"

#### nameref works, via 'declare -n' or 'local -n'
declare -n arr_ref=SECOND
echo '${arr_ref[@]}:' "${arr_ref[@]}"
echo '${!arr_ref[@]}:' "${!arr_ref[@]}"
echo '${#arr_ref[@]}:' "${#arr_ref[@]}"
```

### The result:

##### ordinary variable assignment does NOT work

```
${any_var[@]}: FIRST
${!any_var[@]}: 0
${#any_var[@]}: 1
```

##### nameref works, via 'declare -n' or 'local -n'

```
${arr_ref[@]}: monde ba     # values of the associative array / map
${!arr_ref[@]}: bonjour fu  # keys of the associative array / map
${#arr_ref[@]}: 2           # size of the associative array / map
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters

> Array variables cannot be given the nameref attribute. However, **nameref variables can reference array variables and subscripted array variables.**

Meanwhile, **variable indirection**, or more correctly [**indirect expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), which also uses the exclamation point (!), it requires the variable or parameter to be NOT a nameref:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), **and parameter is not a nameref**, it introduces a level of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the only way:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A FIRST=( [hello]=world [foo]=bar )
declare -A SECOND=( [bonjour]=monde [fu]=ba )
declare -A usethisarray
for key in ${!FIRST[@]}; do
    usethisarray["$key"]="${FIRST["$key"]}"
done
echo ${usethisarray[hello]}
echo ${usethisarray[foo]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

[bob in ~] ARRAY=(one two three)

[bob in ~] echo ${ARRAY[*]}
one two three

[bob in ~] echo $ARRAY[*]
one[*]

[bob in ~] echo ${ARRAY[2]}
three

[bob in ~] ARRAY[3]=four

[bob in ~] echo ${ARRAY[*]}
one two three four

Reference below:

See the link for more information:
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html

Comment: Sorry also try this link. More to do with what you was asking.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660010/bash-how-to-assign-an-associative-array-to-another-variable-name-e-g-rename-t

Comment: The text isn't really what I was looking for, as that's just standard array manipulation.  The other stackoverflow link is a little closer, as it talks about renaming an associate array.  What I need is a way to indirectly reference the correct associate array (my script has a few different ones).  I want to be able to set a variable to reference/copy the correct one when needed.

Comment: This has an example in direct reference to arrays:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180714/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-using-indirect-reference

Answer (score 0):

String Variable Indirection

```
ARRAY=([a]=1 [b]=2 [c]=3)

name="ARRAY"

eval a=\${$name['a']}

eval b=\${$name['b']}

eval c=\${$name['c']}

echo "$a$b$c"

Output>>> 123

eval $array['a']=10             

echo ${ARRAY['a']}


Output>>> 10
```