# Access bash associate array via variable indirection

Tags: arrays, bash, associative

I wish to access an associative array using a variable. The example in the accepted answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099059/can-you-assign-associative-arrays-to-variables-in-bash) is exactly what I want:

```
$ declare -A FIRST=( [hello]=world [foo]=bar )
$ alias=FIRST
$ echo "${!alias[foo]}"
```

however this does not work for me when using bash 4.3.48 or bash 3.2.57.
It does however work if I don't declare ("declare -A") the array i.e. this works:

```
$ FIRST[hello]=world 
$ FIRST[foo]=bar
$ alias=FIRST
$ echo "${!alias[foo]}"
```

Is there any problem with not declaring the array?

Comment: There's a huge problem: it creates a numerically-indexed array, rather than an associative (string-indexed) array. Since `hello` and `foo` aren't defined, `FIRST[hello]` and `FIRST[foo]` are both equivalent to `FIRST[0]`.

Comment: So as Gordon said, the second will not work: `echo "${!alias[foo]}" "${!alias[hello]}"` will output `bar bar`. The `world` is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just as expected, you just missed out defining one more level of indirection to access the value,

```
declare -A first=()
first[hello]=world 
first[foo]=bar
alias=first
echo "${!alias[foo]}"
```

The above result would obviously be empty as the other answer points out as there is no reference created yet to the array key. Now define an `item` to introduce a second level of indirect reference to point out to the actual `key` value.

```
item=${alias}[foo]
echo "${!item}"
foo
```

Now point item to the next key `hello`

```
item=${alias}[hello]
echo "${!item}"
world
```

Or a more detailed example would be, to run a loop over the keys of the associative array

```
# Loop over the keys of the array, 'item' would contain 'hello', 'foo'
for item in "${!first[@]}"; do    
    # Create a second-level indirect reference to point to the key value
    # "$item" contains the key name 
    iref=${alias}["$item"]
    # Access the value from the reference created
    echo "${!iref}"
done
```