# Using Ternary operator to assign an array to another variable in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, ternary-operator

I have two arrays in a bash script 
say

```
ConfigA=("hostname1" "hostname2")
ConfigB=("hostname3" "hostname4")
```

Now I am passing an argument to the script specifying which Array I need to work with

For that I came up with a bash equivalent of ternary operator like below

```
int a = (b == 5) ? c : d;

equilvalent in bash

a=$([ "$b" == 5 ] && echo "$c" || echo "$d")
```

I tried to use this in my case as follows

```
env=$1
Config=$([ "$env" == "qa" ]] && echo "${ConfigA[@]}" || echo "${ConfigB[@]}")
```

However in the above case I get the output

```
hostname1 hostname2
```

but Its not an array, since when I try to loop over it, it print both at once.

I have also tried to surround the array within `()` like

```
Config=$([ "$env" == "qa" ]] && echo "( ${ConfigA[@]} )" || echo "( ${ConfigB[@]} )")
```

but that also doesn't help.

How do I assign the array to a new variable with a ternary operator?

I understand I can do it with a `if-else` condition, but I would like to do it with ternary operator

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of having `()` within quotes in the second case, another approach to assign array to a variable like

```
[ "$env" == "qa" ]] && Config=( "${ConfigA[@]}" ) || Config( "${ConfigB[@]}" )
```

works

What happened in

```
Config=$([ "$env" == "qa" ]] && echo "( ${ConfigA[@]} )" || echo "( ${ConfigB[@]} )")
```

was that echo converted the array to a string and appended the `()` around it and hence it did not work

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to copy array from a variable to another in `bash`.

According to this [Bash: How to assign an associative array to another variable name (e.g. rename the variable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660010/bash-how-to-assign-an-associative-array-to-another-variable-name-e-g-rename-t#8881121|link), a workaround you could use is the following:

```
[[ "$env" == "qa" ]] && eval $(declare -p ConfigA | sed 's/ConfigA/Config/') || eval $(declare -p ConfigB | sed 's/ConfigB/Config/')
echo ${Config[*]}
hostname3 hostname4
```

Comment: And what if the source array's name is contained in it as an element or a substring thereof, e.g.  `x=(x y z)` or `a=(abc def)`

Comment: @Leon in that case best is to loop over all elements of the array, as suggested in the link I mentioned