# Bash check if array of variables have values or not

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array of variables. I want to check if the variables have a value using the for loop.

I am getting the values into loop but the if condition is failing

```
function check {
    arr=("$@")
    for var in "${arr[@]}"; do
        if [ -z $var ] ; then
            echo $var "is not available"
        else
            echo $var "is available"
        fi
    done
}

name="abc"
city="xyz"
arr=(name city state country)
check ${arr[@]}
```

For the above I am getting all as **available**

Expected output is

```
name is available
city is available
state is not available
country is not available
```

Comment: `var` in your loop takes on the values _name_, _city_, _state_ and _country_. [ -z ... ] tests whether the length of the argument is zero. None of those words has zero length, so the `else` branch is taken every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for your task

```
if [ -z "${!var}" ] ; then
    echo $var "is not available"
else
    echo $var "is available"
fi
```

Explanation, this method uses an indirect variable expansion, this construction `${!var}` will expand as value of variable which name is in `$var`.

Changed `check` function a bit

```
check () {
    for var in "$@"; do
        [[ "${!var}" ]] && not= || not="not "
        echo "$var is ${not}available"
    done
}
```

And another variant using `declare`

```
check () {
    for var in "$@"; do
        declare -p $var &> /dev/null && not= || not="not "
        echo "$var is ${not}available"
    done
}
```

From `declare` help

```
$ declare --help
declare: declare [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
    Set variable values and attributes.
    Declare variables and give them attributes.  If no NAMEs are given,
    display the attributes and values of all variables.
    ...
    -p  display the attributes and value of each NAME
    ...
```

Actually all vars can be checked at once using this

```
check () {
    declare -p $@ 2>&1 | sed 's/.* \(.*\)=.*/\1 is available/;s/.*declare: \(.*\):.*/\1 is not available/'
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can explain the change.

Comment: -z string
              True if the length of string is zero.

Comment: This has a bug - variables with values with spaces will result in an error message from `test`.

Comment: If space isn't valid value than it's not a bug it's a feature)

Comment: And i just followed OPs style

Answer (score 0):

While indirection is a possible solution, it is [not really recommended](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection) to use. A safer way would be to use an associative array:

```
function check {
    eval "declare -A arr="${1#*=}
    shift
    for var in "$@"; do
        if [ -z "${arr[$var]}" ] ; then
            echo $var "is not available"
        else
            echo $var "is available"
        fi
    done
}

declare -A list
list[name]="abc"
list[city]="xyz"

check "$(declare -p list)" name city state country
```

This returns:

```
name is available
city is available
state is not available
country is not available
```

---

The following question was used to create this answer:
[How to rename an associative array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660010/how-to-rename-an-associative-array-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

For newer Bash versions (I think ~4.3), there's no need to use `eval` or any other abundant code.

Checking, if an array has any contents, is as simple as:

```
if [[ ${array[@]} ]]; then
    echo -e "Array has ${#array[@]} elements"
fi
```

Any whitespace elements will also count as content here; to ignore them, one could either use a whitespace-negating RegEx in the condition test, or iterate over the array and check each element.

There's also the possibility to use `named references`, to avoid superfluous array value copying and expansions, when passing arrays as arguments to functions:

```
declare -a emptyArray
declare -a array=( TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 )
declare -a onlyBlanksArray=('   ' ' ' '  ')
declare -a withBlanksArray=('   ' ' 1 ' '  ')

# Checks if an array has blank/non-blank elements (is non-empty)
has_elements() {
    local -n aRef="$1"
    [[ ${aRef[@]} ]]
}

# Checks if an array contains only blank elements
has_only_blanks() {
    local -n aRef="$1"
    [[ ${aRef[@]} == +([[:space:]]) ]]
}

if has_elements array; then
    echo -e "Array has ${#array[@]} elements"
fi

if ! has_elements emptyArray; then
    echo -e "ARRAY IS EMPTY"
fi

if has_only_blanks onlyBlanksArray; then
    echo -e "Is blanks-only array"
fi

if ! has_only_blanks withBlanksArray; then
    echo -e "ARRAY CONTAINS NON-BLANK ELEMENTS"
fi
```