# Define hash tables with arrays as values in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, hash

I know this is almost too complicated for scripting purposes, but bear with me.

I know how you can declare arrays:

```
arr=(hello world)
echo ${arr[1]} # "world"
```

And I know that you can use hash maps in bash:

```
declare -A map=([hello]=world [foo]=bar)
echo ${map[hello]} # "world"
```

But can you have hash maps that have arrays as values in bash? I've tried several syntaxes, but usually I got a hash map, which had whitespace seperated list of string as the value associated with the hash

EDIT:

An example: I want to write an adapter `toolNew` for a cmdline tool `toolOld`. Both just printout some information about the system.

`toolOld` can take nine different arguments `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `b1`, ...,  or `c3`, which I want to simplify.

I.e. `toolNew` only takes three differen arguments `a`, `b`, or `c`.

The (imo) cleanest way to do this would be to have a function

```
toolNew() {
    newArgument="$1"
    for argument in "${argumentMap[newArgument][@]}"; do
        toolOld "$argument"
    done
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: No. Arrays are not first-class values in `bash`. Instead, the shell provides array-like syntax that basically disguises the uses of similarly named variables. `ksh` does allows nested arrays, but if you need this type of rich data structure, something other than shell is a much better choice.

Comment: Bash does not support multidimensional arrays (hashes being considered 'associative arrays').

Comment: You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/6151190/7673414 for a method of faking things though  (basically make your keys something like `hello,1`, `hello,2`, and then generate a key based on the original hash key and index you're looking for.

Comment: Instead of actually storing arrays, you could store their *names*  in the map and use `eval` to retrieve their values. It's terribly unsafe but possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent enough version of bash you could emulate this with functions:

1. Create array variables which name could be, e.g., the concatenation of your map keys and values (`helloworld`, `foobar`...).
2. Use variable references (`declare -n`) to reference them.

Example:

```
declare -A map=([hello]=world [foo]=bar)

function set_entry ()
{
    local key="$1"
    local val="${map[$1]}"
    declare -n entry="${key}${val}"
    entry[$2]=$3
}

get_entry ()
{
    local key="$1"
    local val="${map[$1]}"
    declare -n entry="${key}${val}"
    echo "${key}${val}[$2]=${entry[$2]}"
}

declare -a helloworld=( 0 1 2 )
declare -a foobar=( 3 4 5 )
```

And then:

```
$ get_entry hello 1
helloworld[1]=1
$ get_entry foo 0
foobar[0]=3
$ set_entry foo 0 7
$ get_entry foo 0
foobar[0]=7
```