# Optimize prefix checks of lines while iterating through file

Tags: bash, while-loop, prefix, prefix-tree

I'm writing a script in the form

```
while read LINE 
do
    [[ $LINE =~ ^headertag1 ]] && function1 && continue
    [[ $LINE =~ ^headertag2 ]] && function2 && continue
    ...
done < filename
```

As the number of tags increase, I will be doing too many checks per line. I can trying sorting the common tags higher up, but I don't think it solves the fundamental issue. I'm not a software engineer. Are there programming concepts/methods that can improve this situation?

Comment: Can you generalize your functions `function1` and `function2`? If so, probably. Would be nice to know what varies between these functions.

Comment: @stephanmg I will be parsing for information with regexes, usually in the form <<< $LINE | perl -pe 'regex'

Comment: Are the functions completely different? Can you show examples for both functions? And how many functions you expect?

Comment: @stephanmg Yes they very different because every line for a tag is unique from another tag. eg In case of headertag1, it could be perl -pe 's/hello bye//' ; for headertag2, it could be perl -pe 's/apples (oranges )bananas /$1 are delicious/'

Comment: I see. How about defining a map?

Comment: @stephanmg You mean associative arrays? I'm not sure if I follow.

Comment: Well, in your case, you know the following: Tag1 -> Some Regex, Tag2 -> Some Other Regex, Tag 3 -> Yet another regex. Is this correct?

Comment: @stephanmg That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure here, but if you look for tidying up your code and feel bored by adding these if guards repetitively, then maybe this idea will help:

```
#!/bin/bash

tags[tag1]="some regex1"
tags[tag2]="some regex2"
tags[tag3]="some regex3"

function action() {
  echo "perl -pe '${tags[$tag]} other-file.txt'"
}

while read LINE; do
  for tag in "${!tags[@]}"; do
    [[ $LINE =~ ^$tag ]] && action "${tags[$tag]}"
  done
done < filename
```

Not sure if the OP is asking something like this.

Comment: The solution by Michal using BASH_REMATCH as the key for associative arrays with your recommendation fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for two you can first find the longest common prefix of both (here people were wondering how to do that in Bash [Longest common prefix of two strings in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973088/longest-common-prefix-of-two-strings-in-bash)), then first check whether the lines start with it and then after stripping it from both the tag and the line check whether the lines start with the rest of it.

For more than two, you need to make a trie — also known as a prefix tree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie .

That Wikipedia article says

> *For the space-optimized presentation of prefix tree, see [compact prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_prefix_tree).*

And having **longest** common prefixes, that's what you're gonna have.

Since [Bash doesn't have multidimensional associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149679/multidimensional-associative-arrays-in-bash), you will have to either consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Implementation_strategies or embed some other scripting language, like Perl or Python — or GNU Awk (`gawk`), which, unlike to standard Awk, [introduces multidimensional associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html).

## Using the optimization of Bash's associative arrays implementation

As suggested in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763359/reduce-checks-per-line-while-looping-through-file#comment103813541_58763359), we may consider taking just the tag with a simpler regex and using it as a key for associative array which are somewhat optimized in Bash (we can investigate how well-suited for our needs in the sources:

- https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/assoc.c
- https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/assoc.h
- https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.c
- https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/hashlib.h

**if we know what it is delimited by** — like, **if we know that it is always immediately followed by a `:` or something** while not containing it, and using a simpler regex like:

```sh
[[ $LINE =~ ^(.*): ]] && "${DICTIONARY_OF_FUNCTIONS["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"]}"
```

## or Using the optimization of Bash's functions store

if all your tags are like, `/[a-z][a-z0-9]+/` or otherwise accepted by Bash as function names, and delimited as in the method with Bash's associative arrays, then you can use the above method for interpolating function names, like,

```sh
function the_function_for_tag_headertag1() {
    echo "hey it's the first one"
}
[[ $LINE =! ^(.*): ]] && {
    func_name="the_function_for_tag_${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    type "${func_name}" && "${func_name}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, using BASH_REMATCH with associative arrays seemed to be the better solution.

Comment: That's a great way to do this. If the delimiter is somehow captured by a regex, this is great.

Answer (score 1):

The test that you perform on each tag

```
    [[ $LINE =~ ^headertag1 ]] && function1 && continue
```

Is extremely cheap (in memory regexp. Most likely, it will take a fraction of the IO time associate with reading the LINE (from file, or other process). Unless you are performing the test large number of times, this implementation is reasonable.

**Note about style:**
If all pattern are prefix match (or other simple constructs), consider using `bash` case statement

```
case "$LINE" in
   header1*) function1 ;;
   header2*) function2 ;;
   ...
esac
```

This will make the code more elegant, but not change the performance - both the RE and the wildcard are simple.

Comment: while the test is extremely cheap, the file can be very long. If there is a better way of approaching it, I'll take it.

Comment: @user121392 I think that you might be overestimated the cost of the regex/pattern match. This processing is dominated by (1) cost of executing function1/function2 - external perl scripts and (2) potentially IO bound. I do not think that you can squeeze any meaningful speedup from working on the pattern, regardless of the number of lines. Unless there 1000s patterns :-)

Comment: It would help if you can add information to the question about the problems - eg., number of lines, number of patterns, processing time for each function*, etc. Hard to work without those details